# Removing Partial text from row column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, str-replace

I have a scenario where I am having issue is to remove partial data from it.

I have test case below, there are two different columns data one contains single entry to remove, second contains multiple entries to remove.

```
Adjusted By Abbr Malkum on 02/06/2014 5:10:12 PM  Session 1 Time-In changed from 9:14 AM    to 9:16 AM  Session 1 Time-Out changed from 9:15 AM to "Not Set"   with Notes: Forgot to clock     out, Automatically adjusted.  
Adjusted By Abbr Malkum on 02/06/2014 5:07:27 PM  Session 1 Time-In changed from 10:48 AM    to 10:50 AM  Adjusted By Abbr Malkum on 02/06/2014 5:07:34 PM  Session 1 Time-In changed from 10:50 AM to "Not Set"
```

I want to remove a dynamic string from given data. i.e

```
"Adjusted By Abbr Malkum on 02/06/2014 5:10:12 PM "
```

from first line starting from **Adju...** till start of **Session** text

any body can help?
I am not much expert in SQL server, but I am sure there must some Index finding and then replacing

Answer (score 1):

The functions you're looking for are CHARINDEX, or PATINDEX, LEFT, SUBSTRING and REPLACE. The first one is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx